# COBOL - copy an array to another array

Tags: arrays, cobol

how to copy an array  to another array in cobol ?

```
A PIC 9999 occurs 5.
B PIC 9999 occurs 5.
```

i need to copy A to B. anyone can help me ?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Storage

```
01 AA.
   03 A PIC 9999 occurs 5.

01 BB.
   03 B PIC 9999 occurs 5.
```

Procedure:

```
MOVE AA TO BB.
```

HTH!

Comment: this make scene. how if i want copy index by index ?  is there any way to get array length ?

Comment: @mohammad To a certain extent if your COBOL support `occurs depending on ...` http://www.3480-3590-data-conversion.com/article-cobol-occurs.html

Comment: Also remember that you can use Figurative Constants as array dimensions if the array length is not going to change

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for a loop:

```
01  AA-Length Pic S9(8) Binary value +0.
01  BB-Length Pic S9(8) Binary value +0.
01  II        Pic S9(8) Binary value +0.

...and...

Compute AA-Length = Length of AA / Length of A(1)
Compute BB-Length = Length of BB / Length of B(1)

Perform varying II from 1 by 1
  until II > AA-Length or II > BB-Length

  Move A (II) to B (II)

End-Perform
```

Comment: Thanks for this. this one is more suitable for the issue that we are having.

Comment: This is the safest way to work with tables in cobol - dynamically check the upper bound and do not iterate beyond that. Might also suggest continuing to INITIALIZE elements in B having indices larger than AA-Length (if there are any).